# Linking one task to another from within CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

In a Django project, there are a couple of Celery tasks defined in a `tasks.py` within the directory of the main Django app. A `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` in `settings.py` is being used to schedule some tasks to run periodically.

Is there a way to link the output of one Celery task to another Celery task in a similar vein to below? Say `export_to_csv` returns a file path and `upload_file` accepts as input a file path.

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'do-something': {
        'task': 'myproj.tasks.export_to_csv',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=12, minute=30),
        'args': (1, 2, 3),
        'options': {
            'link': 'myproj.tasks.upload_file'
        }
    },
}
```

Something similar to below works:

```
from myproj.tasks import upload_file

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'do-something': {
        'task': 'myproj.tasks.export_to_csv',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=12, minute=30),
        'args': (1, 2, 3),
        'options': {
            'link': upload_file.s()
        }
    },
}
```

but then the `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` can't be located in `settings.py` anymore due to circular importing. The first example does not work, nor does it when the 'link' string is `myproj.tasks.upload_file.s`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for a function to complete before the second function executes, that's by definition synchronous. Celery is designed to asynchronously execute functions. What if you were to create an additional function which executes synchronously the order dependent functions, and run that function asynchronously with one of the celery decorators? For example:

```
# tasks.py
def export_to_csv( ):
    # export code here

def upload_file( ):
    # upload code here

@shared_task
def export_to_csv_and_upload( ):
    export_to_csv( )
    upload_file( )

# settings.py
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'do-something': {
        'task': 'myproj.tasks.export_to_csv_and_upload',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=12, minute=30),
        'args': (1, 2, 3),
        'options': {
            'link': 'myproj.tasks.upload_file'
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: This option works but I was hoping for a more composable solution similar to the sort of [chaining](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains) you can do with celery tasks in regular code. `export_to_csv` returns a filepath which I wanted to pass straight along to `upload_file`, so the body of `export_to_csv_and_upload` would be more like `upload_file(export_to_csv)`. Although I'm no longer working on the problem that spawned this question, I believe your answer is pretty similar to the solution we used (making another task which called the two subtasks).